# the meaning of "You get people who ~ "

Tags: meaning-in-context

> They ignore our need to obtain a deep understanding of a subject, which includes memorizing and storing a richly structured database. You **get** people who are great improvisers but don’t have depth of knowledge.

What does "get" mean here?

Some definitions are as follows, but is not easy to find the meaning of 'get' here.

1. get = become

You use get with adjectives to mean `become'. For example, if someone gets cold, they become cold, and if they get angry, they become angry.

2. get = start being

Get is used with expressions referring to states or situations. For example, to get into trouble means to start being in trouble.

3. get= to cause

To get someone or something into a particular state or situation means to cause them to be in it.

4. get = to cause sb to do sth
   If you get someone to do something, you cause them to do it by asking, persuading, or telling them to do it.
5. get = to cause sb to move there

To get something or someone into a place or position means to cause them to move there.

Comment: It's an example of a very informal/colloquial English expression. In the example "You get" means "There are".  See the [definition here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/you-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"get" in this context means that there are such people, and that you will run into them at least from time to time. It's idiomatic.